# mysql+php: how to store a html string AS IS

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, encoding

i need to store s tring like this, AS IS in mysql

```
member of the ruling <a href="/tets/Polish_United_Workers%27_Party"
```

but in mysql the %27 is concerted to ' char

how can i keep the sql respecting exactly the string as is?

**UPDATE**:

I send the text

```
var string = 'member of the ruling <a href="/tets/Polish_United_Workers%27_Party"'
```

from javascript to php *(maybe the problem is here?)*

```
$.ajax({
url: myurl,
async:false,
data: "text="+string,
type: "POST",
success: function( data ) {....etc...
```

parte of the sql query on the php file receiving the js call

```
text = addslashes($_POST["text"])
```

Comment: Any chance you can post the actual code? That might shed some light on the possible cause.

Comment: mySQL doesn't convert characters like this. Show the code you are using to insert the string.

Comment: you probably should do that, because its safer to encode before inserting to your database, then code, which will return exactly same output.

Comment: By actual code, we mean *actual code*. Not your edited version of what you *think* we'd like to see. Don't flood that page but, clearly, `text = addslashes($_POST["text"])` is not your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
data: {text:string}
```

instead and let jquery handle the encoding for you. when you insert it to your DB you can call `mysql_real_escape_string` on it before inserting it so that you're not vulnerable to SQL injection and everything gets escaped properly, *or* use a more modern database abstraction layer (PDO).

Comment: +1. Best, let jQuery take care of URL-encoding, and let parameterised queries (eg using `mysqli`) take care of SQL-encoding. It is usually better to use interfaces that take the responsibility for escaping away from you, because escaping is hard to get right. For example JS `escape()` is absolutely the wrong thing for URL-encoding and PHP `addslashes()` is absolutely the wrong thing for SQL-encoding.

Comment: @Francesco: That's the beauty of this. You'd just do `{text:string,time:data}` -- you can add as many arguments as you like.

Answer (score 0):

my bad, i overlooked it and YEs the solution was to add `escape(string)` before submitting to php

arrrhggg